# Can You Explain this with an example.Encountered this when studying HOF in scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

This is the Function.What are the arguments here?is it a function? and what is the return type?

```
def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {  
  def sumf(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {...}  
  sumf  
}
```

Comment: What sort of explanation are you looking for? You need to be a bit more specific about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a <del>function</del> method called `sum`. It takes as parameter one function from `Int` to `Int` and returns a function that when called with a pair of `Int`s returns another `Int`.

The actual result depends on the implementation, but we could for instance define it as:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {  
  def sumf(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    f(a) + f(b)
  }  
  sumf  
}
```

Or simply:

```
def sum(f: Int => Int): (Int, Int) => Int = {  
  (a: Int, b: Int) => f(a) + f(b)
}
```

In that case, you could call it like this for instance:

```
def f(a: Int): Int = a * a
def g(a: Int, b: Int): Int = sum(f)(a, b)
val x: Int = g(3, 4) // x = 25
```

Comment: "That is a function called `sum`" – This is wrong. `sum` is not a function, it is a *method*. Functions and methods are fundamentally different in Scala: functions are objects, methods are not. (Methods belong to objects.) Methods can be generic, functions can't. Methods can have an implicit parameter list, functions can't. Methods can have optional parameters with default arguments, functions can't. Methods can have repeated parameters, functions can't.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in practical terms, in this particular case, it's not terribly relevant.